# Get div class with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need to find/get a class called "group" from a div-tag, with javascript.
after that i want to insert a html button(input=submit) inside that div i just found.

How can this be done with javascript ?

i've tryed this so far, but gets and error: document is not declared!

```
var myMessage = 'Mange tak';
var html_kode = '<input type="submit" onclick="clickedelm = this.value" id="qr_tak" tabindex="1" name="sbutton" title="(Alt + A)" accesskey="a" value="Auto Tak" class="button">';

if(myMessage) {
        var find_class = document.getElementsByClassName('group');
        if (find_class) {
            find_class.innerHTML += html_kode;
        }
    }
```

Comment: JavaScript complaining about `document` not defined hints for something *very* wrong with your code. That code is placed in a real HTML page? Doctype compliant?

Comment: It's a .js file im making.. Trying to make it for Greasemonkey on firefox

Comment: If it's for GreaseMonkey, check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663770/get-div-class-with-javascript/6664032#6664032), I modify the DOM that way and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

```
var myMessage = 'Mange tak';
var html_kode = '<input type="submit" onclick="clickedelm = this.value" id="qr_tak" tabindex="1" name="sbutton" title="(Alt + A)" accesskey="a" value="Auto Tak" class="button">';

$(".find_class").html(html_kode);
```

Comment: I cant use JQ since my final work is for the Greasemonkey plugin for firefox

Comment: @Patrick R: If Briedis' answer does not answer your question, you shouldn't pick it as best answer... [TheBrain's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663770/get-div-class-with-javascript/6663815#6663815) or [patorjk's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663770/get-div-class-with-javascript/6663822#6663822) ones are much more relevant to what you're trying to do.

Comment: This did work, the problem was just that the text im trying to insert into a textarea, was in a iframe, so coundnt hit the textarea. And i also got JQuery to work with GM

Answer (score 5):

getElementsByClassName returns an array of elements
so you need to iterate the find_class variable

```
var find_class = document.getElementsByClassName('group');
for (var i = 0, len = find_class.length; i < len; i++) {
   find_class[i].innerHTML = find_class[i].innerHTML + html_kode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"getElementsByClassName" returns a [set of elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.getElementsByClassName), not a single element. Inside of your if statement, you'd really want to do something like this:

```
var len = find_class.length;
for (var ii = 0; ii < len; ii++) {
    find_class[ii].innerHTML = "new code";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than search by class name, it's usually better to assign an ID to your element, then you can identify it uniquely by its ID:

```
<div id="mydiv">
...
</div>
```

and then you can just do

```
var mydiv = document.getElementById('mydiv');
mydiv.innerHTML = mydif.innerHTML + html_kode;
```

Comment: the class im looking for, thats inside a div, have no ID if that made sence ?

Answer (score 0):

It might be a good idea to use a javascript library (i.e. jQuery).

It would make much more easier to fetch elements by class. Standard javascript hasn't got the ability to fetch something by class (only by id).

If you do decide to use jQuery:

```html
if(myMessage)
{
  var find_class = $('.group');
  if(find_class.length > 0)
  {
    find_class.each(function(){
     $(this).html(html_kode);
    });
  }
}
```

Now if you do not want to use jQuery (Prototype, Dojo, etc.), you might want to search for and ID instead of a class - Just change ***group*** to an id and then use the ***getElementById***

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` is a relatively recent addition to the DOM, and some older browsers may not support it. IE8, I'm looking at you.

Most current browsers should be fine, but there's enough people using old versions of IE that you can't really use `getElementsByClassName` without implementing some kind of fall-back.

The most common fall-back solution is to use JQuery instead, but there are [other](http://robertnyman.com/2008/05/27/the-ultimate-getelementsbyclassname-anno-2008/) [solutions](http://blog.justswell.org/clientside-getelementsbyclassname-cross-browser-implementation/) you can try which simply implement this function without the overhead of the rest of the JQuery library.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you're using it in a GreaseMonkey script:

Have you tried using XPath?

This is an example from a script of mine:

```
var XPath = function (path) {
    return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null).snapshotItem(0);
};

var yourOuterElement = XPath('/html/body/div[3]/form/table/tbody/tr/td/table');

var yourNewElement = document.createElement('input');

yourNewElement.setAttribute('type', 'submit');
yourNewElement.setAttribute('value', 'Send!');

yourOuterElement.appendChild(yourNewElement);
```

You can get the XPath for your `yourOuterElement` through FireBug.

Comment: No i have not.. where can i read about xpath or find a tut on how to get mine to work ?

Comment: @Patrick R: You can find some infos [on GreaseMonkey's wiki](http://wiki.greasespot.net/XPath), from there check the bottom links. It's very useful if the DOM of the page doesn't change and you don't have IDs.